# Pygame stuttering object

Tags: python, rotation, pygame

I got a problem with a python programm, using pygame. I want to make a sun in a solar system spin (rotate). It works partially: the problem about some strange "stuttering" of the sun when running the programm. This stuttering occurs again and again, in a loop. Heres the code:"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame as pg
import pygame.locals as local
import sys

def rot_center(image, angle):
    """rotate an image while keeping its center and size"""
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pg.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image

pg.init()

#deklaration
xres=0
yres=0

#auflösungseinstellungen

try:
    xres=int(sys.argv[1]) #auflösung von der kommandozeile, parameter 1
    yres=int(sys.argv[2]) #auflösung von der kammondozeile, parameter 2

except IndexError:
    xres=800
    yres=600

screen = pg.display.set_mode((xres,yres)) #coords nicht hart coden, variablen nutzen
pg.display.set_caption("future rpg prepreprepalphawhatever")

pg.mouse.set_visible(1)
pg.key.set_repeat(1,30)

clock = pg.time.Clock()


running = 1
rotation_stat = 0.0

while running:
    planet01 = pg.image.load("grafik/menu/planet02.png")
    planet01.set_colorkey((251,0,250), local.RLEACCEL) #load planet01
    sun = pg.image.load("grafik/menu/sun.png") #load sun
    bg = pg.image.load("grafik/menu/bg.png") #load background

    #den hintergrund skalieren, falls auflösung zu hoch
    sizedbg = pg.transform.smoothscale(bg, (xres, yres))

    rotation_stat += 1
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(sizedbg, (0,0))
    screen.blit(planet01, (xres/5-planet01.get_width()/2,yres/2-planet01.get_height()/2))

    orig_rect = sun.get_rect()
    sun = pg.transform.rotate(sun, rotation_stat)
    screen.blit(sun, (xres/2-sun.get_width()/2,yres/2-sun.get_height()/2))
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = sun.get_rect().center
    sun = sun.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()


    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == local.QUIT:
            running = 0
        if event.type == local.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == local.K_ESCAPE:
                pg.event.post(pg.event.Event(local.QUIT))

    pg.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code for loading the images outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but it seems like you are loading the images every time your loop runs which is heavily intensive on your CPU

Comment: Thx for the answer but if i put the code for the loading of the images out of the loop the sun will split up and rotating really strange

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it will solve your problem but try passing DOUBLEBUF to set_mode() like so: self.display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

Comment: ShadowWolf: that's because you're rotating the image that you previously rotated.  The rotated image will be larger, and then you rotate *that*, which makes it larger, etc.  Your image will seem to split apart.

Answer (score 0):

*I have rewritten my answer based on your comments and after having glanced over the pygame docs*

You really do only need to load your images once. What I am doing here is always rotating the originally loaded sun to a new surface, using the incrementing rotation. The rotation always wraps back to 0 degrees. As for the jitter, I am sure that related to an aliasing artifact and maybe even your centering math. But my goal was to address the biggest performance hit which was reading your sun image from disk every frame (30 times a second)

```
import pygame as pg
import pygame.locals as local
import sys

def main():
    pg.init()

    xres=800
    yres=600

    try:
        xres=int(sys.argv[1]) 
        yres=int(sys.argv[2]) 

    except IndexError:
        pass

    screen = pg.display.set_mode((xres,yres)) 
    pg.display.set_caption("future rpg prepreprepalphawhatever")

    pg.mouse.set_visible(1)
    pg.key.set_repeat(1,30)

    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    rotation_stat = 0.0

    planet01 = pg.image.load("earth.png")
    planet01.set_colorkey((251,0,250), local.RLEACCEL) #load planet01

    sun = pg.image.load("sun.png") #load sun
    bg = pg.image.load("bg.png") #load background

    sizedbg = pg.transform.smoothscale(bg, (xres, yres))

    planet_pos = (xres/5-planet01.get_width()/2,yres/2-planet01.get_height()/2)

    running = 1

    xres_cent, yres_cent = xres/2, yres/2

    while running:

        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == local.QUIT:
                running = 0
            if event.type == local.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == local.K_ESCAPE:
                    pg.event.post(pg.event.Event(local.QUIT))

        rotation_stat += 1
        if rotation_stat % 360 == 0:
            rotation_stat = 0.0

        screen.blit(sizedbg, (0,0))
        screen.blit(planet01, planet_pos)

        sun_rect = sun.get_rect()
        sun_rotated = pg.transform.rotate(sun, rotation_stat)

        center = sun_rotated.get_rect().center
        sun_pos = (xres_cent-center[0], yres_cent-center[1])
        screen.blit(sun_rotated, sun_pos)

        pg.display.flip()

    pg.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but i need the xres and yres to put the sun in the center of the screen

Comment: @ShadowWolf: Alright, I have just rewritten my answer to address how you load the sun.

Comment: @ShadowWolf: If this answer solved your problem you should accept it with the green checkmark. Thanks!